# Show that if $f : G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve in $G$ then $f \circ \gamma$ is also a recifiable curve.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f : G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve in $G$, then $f \circ \gamma$  is also a rectifiable curve.

---

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your definition of rectifiable. Presumably $G$ is an open set.

If rectifiable implies continuity, then $\Gamma = \gamma([a,b]) \subset G$ is compact, and since $f$ is analytic, then so is $f'$, which is bounded on $\Gamma$ by some $L$. If $p_0 = a, p_1,...,p_n =b$ is a sufficiently small (so that each pair $p_i,p_{i+1}$ is contained in some open ball contained in $G$) partition of $[a,b]$, then $\sum |f(\gamma(p_{i+1}))-f(\gamma(p_i)))| \le L \sum |\gamma(p_{i+1})-\gamma(p_i))| \le L l(\gamma)$. It follows that $f \circ \gamma$ is rectifiable and $l(f \circ \gamma) \le L\  l(\gamma)$.

**Addendum**: The above argument needs a little refinement, thanks to LEY for point it out. For $z \in G$ let $r_z>0$ be such that $\overline{B}(z,r_z) \subset G$ and
consider the open cover $B(z,{1 \over 2}r_z)$. Since $\Gamma$ is compact there is a finite open cover $B(z_k,{1 \over 2}r_{z_k})$. The set $\cup_k \overline{B}(z,r_z) \subset G$ is compact, so $|f'|$ is bounded by $L$. Choose the partition such that $|\gamma(p_{i+1})-\gamma(p_i))|< {1 \over 2}\min_k r_{z_k}$. It follows that any two successive points lie in the some $B(z_k,r_{z_k})$ (which is convex) and so the mean value theorem applies.

If rectifiable does not imply continuous, then it is not true. Take $G = B(0,1)$, $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$, and $\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} t & t \in [0,1) \\ 0 & t = 1 \end{cases}$. An easy computation shows that $l(\gamma) = 2$ (hence rectifiable). Since $(f \circ \gamma)([0,1])$ is unbounded, it is clear that $f \circ \gamma$ is not rectifiable.

Comment: Why $|f(\gamma(p_{i+1}))-f(\gamma(p_{i}))|\leq L|\gamma(p_{i+1})-\gamma(p_{i})|?$ If we are using the mean value inequality, we might need to take $\sup_{[\gamma(p_{i}),\gamma(p_{i})]}|f'| $instead of L, where [a,b] stands for the segment joining a,b?

Comment: @LEY Good catch, I added an elaboration above.

Comment: I think now it's perfect. Could you please also check my answer below? I am just reading conway's complex analysis and I don't know if my solution works :)

Comment: It think it would be better @copper.hat to have shown more clear the use of the fact of the curve of being rectifiable.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo I am not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: I think it's better for me to review the concept of rectifiable curve first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the anlogue of the Fundamental Theorem of Caculus for line integrals, for any partition $P$:
\begin{align}\sum_i|f(\gamma(p_{i+1}))-f(\gamma(p_{i}))|&=\sum_i|\int_{\gamma_i}f'\mathrm d\gamma|\\&\leq \sum_{i}\int_{\gamma_i}|f'||\mathrm d\gamma|\\&\leq\sum_i\sup_{\{\gamma_i\}}|f'|\mathrm V(\gamma_i)\\&\leq\sup_{\{\gamma\}}|f'|\mathrm V(\gamma)\end{align}
where $\gamma_i$ stands for the restriction of $\gamma$ on $[p_i,p_{i+1}]$, and $V(\gamma)$ the total variation of $\gamma$.
Hence $$\mathrm V(f\circ\gamma)\leq \sup_{\{\gamma\}}|f'|\mathrm V(\gamma)$$

Comment: Looks fine. I presume you are using some combination of Conway's Theorems 1.17 & 1.18.

Answer (score 0):

If on the image of $\gamma$, $f'$ is bounded, or $f$ is locally Lipschitz, you are done.  Analyticity is too strong a condition.